# Can "Corporation" structured data on pages about other companies get rich snippets for my site?

Tags: seo, google, schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data

On my website I have a list of several hundred companies. And after you click any of them, you are navigating to the page, where you are able to see their details. For SEO on each company page, can I use "Corporation" schema markup to get a rich result for the company?

For the example, I have a few words about **Google Inc** on my page, so can I use some simple markup?

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Corporation",
  "name": "Google Inc",
  "address": "some address",
  "description": "A few words about Google inc."
}
```

Or maybe the rich snippet is reserved only for Google's own website? Am I going to get some penalties for this? Or it will help me with SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not document any rich snippets related to Corporation outside the option to mark up your own [businesses logo](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo).

There is no harm in including the markup. Maybe another system may find it useful.